# ssl.SSLWantWriteError when uploading a youtube video through google cloud services

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, youtube-api

The basis of what I am doing is uploading a file to youtube after downloading something from twitch. (Youtube data api v3)
Here is the code I am running:

```
import os
import subprocess
import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def download_vod(url, file_path):
    command = f'streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 -o "{file_path}" "{url}" best'
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

def upload_to_youtube(video_file, title, description):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('client_secret.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'])
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part='snippet,status',
        body={
            'snippet': {
                'title': title,
                'description': description,
            },
            'status': {
                'privacyStatus': 'private',  # Change privacy status as desired
            }
        },
        media_body=video_file
    )
    response = request.execute()

    video_id = response['id']
    print(f"Video uploaded successfully. Video ID: {video_id}")

def main():
    while True:
        url = input("Enter the Twitch VOD URL (or 'q' to quit): ")
        if url == 'q':
            break

        file_name = input("Enter the desired file name (excluding extension): ")
        file_path = file_name  # You can specify a directory path here if desired

        download_vod(url, file_path + ".mp4")
        print("Download complete!")

        upload = input("Upload to YouTube? (y/n): ")
        if upload.lower() == 'y':
            title = input("Enter video title: ")
            description = input("Enter video description: ")
            upload_to_youtube(file_path + ".mp4", title, description)

        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error only relates to the uploading to youtube.
Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\myrai\OneDrive\Desktop\TTV-YT\main.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\myrai\OneDrive\Desktop\TTV-YT\main.py", line 49, in main
    upload_to_youtube(file_path + ".mp4", title, description)
  File "c:\Users\myrai\OneDrive\Desktop\TTV-YT\main.py", line 28, in upload_to_youtube
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1724, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1367, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1076, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 998, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1237, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "C:\Users\myrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1206, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2396)
```

Also yes, I know that plugging into the router directly worked for someone with a similar issue however this is something I am not capable of doing at the moment.

Edit: My network should be stable. Ping tests to google are a consistent 1-6ms. Uploading youtube videos manually works. I'm not using a proxy or firewall which can interfere.
(New to python btw)

Comment: The error `ssl.SSLWantWriteError` is caused by a networking hardware issue or networking configuration issue. Basically, the TCP/IP stack is hung trying to send data over the network. There is nothing to fix in your code. You must fix your network.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the clarification. My network connection is stable. What specifically would the network problem be from?

Comment: What testing have you performed to verify your network is not the issue? Put those details in your question and not via comments.